# How to open PDF File From oracle forms 11g?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms, oraclereports, oracle-fusion-middleware

I am using Oracle Database 11gR2 with Oracle Forms 11gR2. I have PDF File Saved on Server Machine. I created button with Name "HELP" Manual PDF File. Now i want when user click on button on their local machine then PDF File open from server machine.

I found this code:

```
host('rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler c:\file_name.pdf');
```

Is this code run correctly? Oracle Forms 11g

Comment: Does it run correctly? I don't know; did you try it? How about a simple `host('c:\file_name.pdf');` which might invoke default PDF reader on a computer and open the PDF file?

Comment: Do I need add IP Address of server machine?

Comment: HOST runs on a server, so - I don't think so.

Comment: Can I add something in this code without C or D drive. If i did not write anything on C Letter

Comment: Try and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can create such a Procedure within your form :

```
Procedure Pr_Print( i_document varchar2 ) Is
   pl_id           paramlist;
   pl_list         paramlist;
   my_rep_server   varchar2(500);
Begin
   pl_list := Get_Parameter_List('tmpdata');
   if not Id_Null(pl_list) then
     Destroy_Parameter_List(pl_list);
   end if;
   pl_list := Create_Parameter_List('tmpdata');

   set_report_object_property('RP2RRO', report_filename, i_document );
   set_report_object_property('RP2RRO', report_server, my_rep_server);
   add_parameter(pl_id, 'column1', text_parameter, :col1 );
   add_parameter(pl_id, 'column2', text_parameter, :col2 );

   rp2rro.rp2rro_run_product(reports, i_document, synchronous, runtime, 
                             filesystem, pl_id, null);
End;
```

where `rp2rro.rp2rro_run_product` is a method coming from `rp2rro.pll` ( *a binary library module supplied by Oracle* ),
assuming you have `col1` and `col2` text fields in it.

And call it from a button's `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` trigger with the code :

`Pr_Print('myDocument');`

*P.S. the library `rp2rro.pll` should be installed and configured within the application server, too. Since `Reports 11g` runs on app. server as a web-based application.*

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `WEB.SHOW_DOCUMENT(url,’_blank’);` in your `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` trigger